# Getting the same double values in JavaScript from C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I wish to have C# print out double value the same for double value print out by JS.

For JavaScript,
I have

```
var x=value;
console.log(value);
```

For C#
I use the following code to mimic JavaScript

```
 string number = decimal.Parse(((double)value).ToString("G17"), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float).ToString();
  Console.WriteLine(number);
```

When

```
value=4.84143144246472090e+00
```

I got

```
JS:4.841431442464721
C#:4.8414314424647209
```

When I used `.ToString("G16")` for C#, I will get equal for JS and C# for previous value. Nevertheless, for

```
value=1.03622044471123109e-01
```

I got

```
JS:0.10362204447112311 
C#:0.1036220444711231
```

How to I make C# double value have same printout for JS?

Just FYI:

Information for JS Precision
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp

Information for C# precision 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.toFixed()`:

```
console.log(value.toFixed(16));
```

The `.toFixed()` function returns a string, in case it's not obvious.

Comment: Thanks, but I need the C# behavior to mimic JS, not the other way round.