# Double value not displayed correctly in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I want to display declarated C# variable (double type) in js script, but value is display in wrong format.

C# code:

```
double value = 13.409334;
```

Javascript code:

```
console.log(@value);
```

Result:

[image]

I try use ToString():

```
console.log(@value.ToString("F");
```

but result is this same.

Comment: The following might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511137/getting-the-same-double-values-in-javascript-from-c-sharp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the same double values in JavaScript from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511137/getting-the-same-double-values-in-javascript-from-c-sharp)